# Trying to reference a header with no id, within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementsbyname

I am essentially creating a simple looking progress bar. I have 4 sections, and above each section is the progress bar. For example, in section 2, the progress bar for this will have step 1 highlighted in green. For section 3, the progress bar for this will have step 1 and 2 highlighted in green etc.

Class step-incomplete is the same as step-complete just with the background difference.

At the moment, I have a few problems. I can't find out how to reference the headers in each div. Whatever I do I get nothing or [object HTMLHeadingElement]. The loop itself is fine, but I can't find a way to change the class name for a specific header, in a specific div.

Code is below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .step-complete {
      display: inline;
      border-style: hidden;
      background: green;
    }
    .step-incomplete {
      display: inline;
      border-style: hidden;
      background: none;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var numOfSections = 4;

    function changeColour() {
      for (i = 1; i <= numOfSections; i++) {
        if (i != 1) {
          alert(i);
          var progress = document.getElementById('progress-' + i).id;
          alert(progress);
          for (j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
            alert(j);
            var header = document.getElementsByName("step-" + j);
            alert(progress.header.className);

          }
        }
      }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      changeColour();
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="push" onclick="changeColour()">click me</button>


  <div id="progress-1">
    <h1 name="step-1" class="step-incomplete">Step1</h1>
    <h1 name="step-2" class="step-incomplete">Step2</h1>
    <h1 name="step-3" class="step-incomplete">Step3</h1>
    <h1 name="step-4" class="step-incomplete">Step4</h1>
  </div>
  <h1 id="header1">Header1</h1>
  <p>..................
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
  </p>

  <div id="progress-2">
    <h1 name="step-1" class="step-incomplete">Step1</h1>
    <h1 name="step-2" class="step-incomplete">Step2</h1>
    <h1 name="step-3" class="step-incomplete">Step3</h1>
    <h1 name="step-4" class="step-incomplete">Step4</h1>
  </div>
  <h1 id="header2">Header2</h1>
  <p>..................
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
  </p>

  <div id="progress-3">
    <h1 name="step-1" class="step-incomplete">Step1</h1>
    <h1 name="step-2" class="step-incomplete">Step2</h1>
    <h1 name="step-3" class="step-incomplete">Step3</h1>
    <h1 name="step-4" class="step-incomplete">Step4</h1>
  </div>
  <h1 id="header3">Header3</h1>
  <p>..................
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
  </p>

  <div id="progress-4">
    <h1 name="step-1" class="step-incomplete">Step1</h1>
    <h1 name="step-2" class="step-incomplete">Step2</h1>
    <h1 name="step-3" class="step-incomplete">Step3</h1>
    <h1 name="step-4" class="step-incomplete">Step4</h1>
  </div>
  <h1 id="header4">Header4</h1>
  <p>..................
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

The end goal is shown in this picture:

[image of end goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcONf.png)

Comment: Can you try recreating the problem in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you are trying to accomplish. Currently what you have doesn't make much sense. You have a name attribute in a `h1` tag, which is not allowed in HTML. You have the same name multiple times, so your `getElementsByName()` will return multiple results. And a the number you store in the variable `progress` has for sure not `header` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To me, I think you're almost there! I'm sure though, using `getElementsByName()`, you have to provide an index, similar to `getElementsByTagName()` or `getElementsByClass()`, so while you have -

> var header = document.getElementsByName("step-" + j);

I think it needs to be

> var header = document.getElementsByName("step-" + j)**[0]**;

with the index added at the end **`[0]`**.

Comment: Well, that is, assuming he has a name in his html for the headers.This should be done differently altogether.

Comment: You will always get just the first item, not the first item under the specific div

Comment: I personally would agree, this is just the first/biggest problem that I noticed - also, If I'm honest, I probably wouldn't have seen the others =)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question, it looks like the problem you're running into is that `document.getElementsByName()` will return ALL the elements on the page with the given name, regardless of which div they're actually in.

You can try instead iterating through the children of each progress div:

```
function changeColour() {
    for(i=1; i<=numOfSections; i++){
        if(i != 1){
            alert(i);
            var progress = document.getElementById('progress-' + i).id;
            alert(progress);
            for(j=0; j<progress.children.length; j++){
                alert(j);
                var segment = progress.children[j];
                alert(segment.className);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the step `<h1>` elements are the only things in the div, this should operate on them in order. If not, you could add an additional step to check the element's name, and even possibly add the children to a Javascript array in some particular order for later reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `querySelector` so you can contain your searches to just the div you are looping over

```
function changeColour() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= numOfSections; i++) {
    if (i != 1) {
      alert(i);
      var progress = document.getElementById('progress-' + i).id;
      alert(progress);
      for (var j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
        // Instead of querying the whole document, query just the current div
        var header = progress.querySelector("h1[step-" + j + "]");
        alert(progress.header.className);


      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could just get the whole list of `h1`s and iterate over those

```
  var h1s = progress.querySelectorAll('h1');
```